# Unescaping HTML with special characters in Python 2.7.3 / Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-2.7, character-encoding, html-parsing, raspberry-pi, python-unicode

I'm stuck here trying to unescape HTML special characters.

The problematic text is

```
Rudimental &amp; Emeli Sandé
```

which should be converted to 
*Rudimental & Emeli Sandé*

The text is downloaded via WGET (outside of python)

To test this, save a ANSI file with this line and import it.

```
import HTMLParser

trackentry = open('import.txt', 'r').readlines()
print(trackentry)
track = trackentry[0]
html_parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

track = html_parser.unescape(track)

print(track)
```

I get this error when a line has *é* in it.

```
*pi@raspberrypi ~/scripting $ python unparse.py
['Rudimental &amp; Emeli Sand\xe9\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unparse.py", line 9, in <module>
    track = html_parser.unescape(track)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 472, in unescape
    return re.sub(r"&(#?[xX]?(?:[0-9a-fA-F]+|\w{1,8}));", replaceEntities, s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)*
```

The same code works fine under windows - I only have problems on the raspberry pi
running Python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python cannot decode '*é*' ('*\xe9*') using the ASCII codec because this character is not 7-bit ASCII.

Your problem (condensed):

```
import HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
input = 'Rudimental &amp; Emeli Sand\xe9'
output = parser.unescape(input)
```

produces

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "problem.py", line 4, in <module>
    output = parser.unescape(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 475, in unescape
    return re.sub(r"&(#?[xX]?(?:[0-9a-fA-F]+|\w{1,8}));", replaceEntities, s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**HTMLParser.unescape()** returns a **unicode** object, and therefore has to convert your input **str**. So it asks for the default encoding (which in your case is ASCII) and fails to interpret '*\xe9*' as an ASCII character (because it isn't). I guess your file encoding is ISO-8859-1 where '*\xe9*' is '*é*'.

There are two easy solutions. Either you do the conversion manually:

```
import HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
input = 'Rudimental &amp; Emeli Sand\xe9'
input = input.decode('iso-8859-1')
output = parser.unescape(input)
```

or you use **codecs.open()** instead of **open()** whenever you are working with files:

```
import codecs
import HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
input = codecs.open("import.txt", encoding="iso-8859-1").readline()
output = parser.unescape(input)
```