# How to parse Vietnamese unicode characters in text

Tags: python, unicode

How to use Python to decode

```
[H&agrave;i kịch] Vợ ơi l&agrave; vợ - V&acirc;n Sơn Bảo Li&ecirc;m & L&ecirc; Huỳnh
```

into this

```
[Hài kịch] Vợ ơi là vợ - Vân Sơn Bảo Liêm & Lê Huỳnh
```

Thanks.

---

I have tried the following code from the above susgeted thread:

```
import re, HTMLParser
title="[H&agrave;i kịch] Vợ ơi l&agrave; vợ - V&acirc;n Sơn Bảo Li&ecirc;m & L&ecirc; Huỳnh"
list_of_html = re.findall("&.+?;", title) 
for e in list_of_html:
    h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
    unescaped = h.unescape(e)
    title = title.replace(e, unescaped)
print title
```

but got an error message:

```
Unsupported characters in input
```

because I have these words in the title "kịch Vợ ơi vợ - Sơn Bảo Huỳnh". How can I correct it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unescaping HTML with special characters in Python 2.7.3 / Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342549/unescaping-html-with-special-characters-in-python-2-7-3-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Look at what your regex captures: it finds `"& L&ecirc;"` – even if non-greedy – and you have an unescaped ampersand, which the HTML parser doesn't like. Change the regex to this: `r"&[A-Za-z]+;"`.